# Xargs `-J` Option

Tags: xargs, options

[This site](http://root42.blogspot.cl/2014/02/how-to-use-find-and-rsync-to-copy-bunch.html) presents the `xargs` command with a `-J` option making able to pass the standard input into a desired position at the command argument:

```
find . -name '*.ext' -print0 | xargs -J % -0 rsync -aP % user@host:dir/
```

but at a [GNU xargs man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) this option is not present.

Which is the way to do this on, for commands accepting this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you were expecting, but in the BSD world (such as macOS) `-I` and `-J` differ in how they pass the multiple "lines" to the command. Example:

```
$ ls
file1 file2 file3

$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -I % rm %
rm file1
rm file2
rm file3

$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -J % rm %
rm file1 file2 file3
```

So with `-I`, xargs will run the command for each element passed to it individually. With `-J`, xargs will execute the command once and concatenate all the elements and pass them as arguments all together.

Some commands such as `rm` or `mkdir` can take multiple arguments and act on them the same way as if you passed a single argument and ran them multiple times. But some apps may change depending how you pass arguments to them. For instance the `tar`. You may create a tar file and then add files to it or you may create a tar file by adding all the files to it in one go.

```
$ find . -iname "*.txt" -or -iname "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -J % tar cjvf documents.tar.bz2 %
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is the `-J` flag for the BSD version of `xargs` I don't believe there's an exact equivalent option for GNU `xargs`. `-J` replaces a single occurrence of *replstr* (e.g. `%`) with each line coming in through standard input. The GNU version has a *similar* option, though: `-I`<sup>1</sup>. However, you can use *replstr* multiple times with that flag.

For use cases where it's unimportant whether there are one or multiple command invocations you should be able to use GNU `xargs -I` as a drop-in replacement. But your example uses `rsync` and I'm sure you don't want multiple invocations of that.

Your best course of action then is to consider alternatives starting with `find` and the `-exec` or `-execdir` action. There are two variations of these. One is analagous to GNU `-I` and the other to BSD `-J`. Take a look at these examples...

```
# Note the escaping of ';'
$ find /tmp -name '*.txt' -exec echo {} \;
/tmp/a.txt
/tmp/b.txt
..
/tmp/z.txt
```

Now compare that to this:

```
$ find /tmp -name '*.txt' -exec echo {} +
/tmp/a.txt /tmp/b.txt .. /tmp/z.txt
```

Only difference between the two is which "modifier" appears at the end, `+` or `;`.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Further confusing things is that the BSD version also has `-I` and it's similar in function to both `-J` and GNU `-I`! But this `-I` is affected by other flags and is most likely not what you are looking for.</sub>

Comment: I am confused, i understood that the `-I % ` is for executing the `command` for every line printed in the previous piped command; 10 lines, 10 executions. and that the `-J %` "would" replace the whole list of lines, just when we do `xargs ls -tr` replacing the whole list at the end. I am actually seeking for the second interpretation

Comment: I actually dont care to stick with `xargs`,  i would like to know a way to pass the previous command into the next one into a given position, like `rsync -aP (find . -name '*.ext' -print0) user@host:dir/` but i dont know if this notation is valid (i am assuming no whitespaces, which i will solve properly)

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about command substitution: `rsync -aP $(find . -name '*.ext' -print0) ...etc`. But you don't want to do that it's not correct...it will break much of the time because of the shell's word splitting and expansions. You're better off using `xargs` like you are or you can look at find's `-exec/-execdir` flag (in particular the second form with `+` modifier).